# Field Accessibility "Data Not Available"

Tags: managed-package, fields, setup

With our managed package, after installing it to another org, I am receiving a bizarre message when I try to view the "Field Accessibility" for any of the objects. If I go into Setup as a Sys Admin, and try to view the "Field Accessibility" under the Security Controls, I get this error:

> Data Not Available
>   The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

I don't know what could be causing this problem. SalesForce documentation has no help on this particular error. I suppose I will need to raise a ticket with SF, but I wanted to check with others to see if this has occurred with anyone else and if there was a resolution available.